# does google openID issue token?

Tags: openid, token

Myself implementented  SSO in my application using Authentication Exchange in c# by Dotnetopenauth

My Doubts follows,

1. On Response of my AX request , i dont receive any token. should i need to send any parameter ?
2. In My Application i need user to sign in on Provider everytime , but rightnow if user clicks checkbox on "sign-in automatically next time" it never asks id and password from user next time .
3. AX fetchResponse null for MyopenId. does it support only Simple Registration?

Request Code:

```
IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(txt_openid_identifier.Text);

    var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
    fetchRequest.Attributes.Clear();
    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First);
    fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last);                       fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.HomeAddress.Country);                
            request.AddExtension(fetchRequest);

            // Issue request to OP
            request.RedirectToProvider();
```

Response Code:

```
using (var openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty())
        {
            var response = openid.GetResponse();

            if (response == null) return;

            switch (response.Status)
            {

                case AuthenticationStatus.Authenticated:
                    string emailID = string.Empty;
                    Session["email"] = string.Empty;
                    Session["name"] = string.Empty;
                    Session["country"] = string.Empty;
                    Session["Accesskey"] = string.Empty;
                    Session["SecretAccesskey"] = string.Empty;

                    var fetchResponse = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();

                    if (fetchResponse.Attributes.Contains(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email))
                    {
                        IList<string> emailAddresses =
                            fetchResponse.Attributes[WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email].Values;
                        emailID = emailAddresses.Count > 0 ? emailAddresses[0] : null;
                    }
                    else
                        emailID = string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that certain providers (i.e. myopenid.com) returned null for a `FetchRequest` whilst returning valid data for `ClaimsRequest`. It appears different providers support different mechanisms for attribute exchange. In the request:

```
var request = openid.CreateRequest(Request.Form["openid_identifier"]);

var sr = new ClaimsRequest
{
    Email = DemandLevel.Request, 
    FullName = DemandLevel.Request
};
request.AddExtension(sr);

var fetchRequest = new FetchRequest();
fetchRequest.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
fetchRequest.Attributes.AddOptional(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName);
request.AddExtension(fetchRequest);

return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
```

and when picking up the response:

```
string email, fullName = String.Empty;
var fetch = response.GetExtension<FetchResponse>();
if (fetch != null)
{
    email = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
    fullName = fetch.GetAttributeValue(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName);
}
var claimResponse = response.GetExtension<ClaimsResponse>();
if (claimResponse != null)
{
    email = claimResponse.Email;
    fullName = claimResponse.FullName;
}
```

Thus we try both ways and hopefully gets the data from at least one of the methods.